# Read values from CSV when columns names are vertical

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have an implementation of CSV helper which currently reads CSV's in the traditional format:

```
Name, Address, Age
"Foo", "Foo's address", 24
"Bar", "Bar's address", 19
```

I use a class map to map the fields by name to my Person object in the following way:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ContentMapper>();
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Person>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

I need an implementation which reads the exact same data but in a vertical format which originates from data where the column names are vertical in the first column and the data follows in columns instead of rows.

```
Name, "Foo", "Bar"
Address, "Foo's address", "Bar's address"
Age, 24, 19
```

What would be the best way to handle a CSV in this format whilst retaining the original mapping?

Comment: vertical formatting in csv should be irrelevant, it is the commas that deliniate the fields, not the column location

Comment: Exactly the problem. My class mapping fails as "Foo" and "Bar" are treated as column names (which do not match the mapping).

Comment: Well you would need something that knows to handle it that way, and traditionally thats not how csv files work

Comment: If you are set on using csvhelper it may be beneficial to pivot the source data to be an expected format first before applying your csvhelper logic to it.

Comment: I don't have the time to write a proper answer but I would suggest reading each row and then iterating over it with GetField, storing the result in a list.  When you've read all the rows, iterate over the lists, writing out the first element, then second etc.  That should get you a "standard" csv which you can read in as normal

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }


    public List<Person> ReadFile(string path)
    {
        char[] charsToTrim1 = {'\\', ' ', '"', '\"'};

        var fileData = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        var outputData = new List<Person>();

        for (var i = 0; i < fileData.Length; i++)
        {
            var tmpData = fileData[i].Split(',');

            for (var j = 0; j < tmpData.Length; j++)
            {
                var t1 = tmpData[j].Trim(charsToTrim1);
                if (j == 0)
                    continue;
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        var tmPerson = new Person {Name = t1};
                        outputData.Add(tmPerson);
                    }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    {
                        outputData[j - 1].Address = t1;
                    }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    {
                        outputData[j - 1].Age = Convert.ToInt32(t1);
                    }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


        return outputData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer here may work for the original example but it's too specific to be an answer to the question.  It doesn't handle field escaping correctly - i.e. fields that themselves contain a comma.

Comment: which fields can contain a comma? Age ? like 16,5 ? or Name Al,ex? or Address 91 Pumpkin Hill Street Seattle WA 98144

Comment: I'm talking about the general case.  It should be clear the OP is just using that data as an example otherwise they would have just fixed it up by hand ;-)   CSV data can include commas, quotes and other special characters.  If you want to know more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values  is a good explanation (see second paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be cleaned up a bit, but it does seem to work.

- Use CsvHelper to pull in the records as `List<dynamic>`
- Rotate the records into a new `List<dynamic>` so the first field in each row becomes the property name of the dynamic record.
- Use CsvHelper to write the new list to memory.
- Use CsvHelper to read the records back in using your `ClassMap`

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var flippedRecords = new List<dynamic>();

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Name,Foo,Bar");
            writer.WriteLine("Address,Foo's address,\"Bar's address with, comma\"");
            writer.WriteLine("Age,24,19");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

            // Get the records from the CSV file.
            var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

            // Rotate the records into a new dynamic list.
            var rows = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();                

            foreach (var row in records)
            {
                rows.Add(row as IDictionary<string, object>);
            }

            for (int i = 2; i <= rows[0].Count; i++)
            {
                var flippedRecord = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

                foreach (var row in rows)
                {
                    flippedRecord.Add((string)row["Field1"], row["Field" + i]);
                }

                flippedRecords.Add(flippedRecord);
            }
        }

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            // Write the new list to memory
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(flippedRecords);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            // Read in the person records using a ClassMap.
            csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonMap>();

            var people = csvReader.GetRecords<Person>().ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("Name");
        Map(m => m.Address);
        Map(m => m.Age);
    }
}
```